# Play a video with flash (with no controls, pause, etc) and stretch to full width and height of page

Tags: video, web, flash, flv

I've managed this so far: [removed url]

The plan is to have that video stretch across the whole page (the flash does, the video itself does not).
Firstly: well aware of the issues - bad performance, horribly stretched/pixelated video. I know this. However a client wants it so we have to do it, simple as that.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved? I've been in touch with the creators of the flash video player I'm currently using and they've confirmed it isn't possible with that flash video player.

Anyone know of any players where it is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this out? http://code.google.com/p/flv-flash-fullscreen-video-player/

Comment: That's worked great - thanks a lot. Trouble I'm having now though is that I can't seem to sit items over it, even with absolute positioning and a high z-index.

Comment: Ah, finally got it sorted (not really the nicest of code, but hey, it'll do). Thanks very much!